# Getting the value of a TextBox after drag and drop in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I have an application that allows you to draw an activity diagram and I need to generate an algorithm  from this diagram.

My question is how to get the value of a Textbox after drag and drop?

Here is the code that I wrote in my button:

```
private void generat_algo(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
           IEnumerable<DesignerItem> designerItems = this.Children.OfType<DesignerItem>();
           IEnumerable<Connection> connections = this.Children.OfType<Connection>();
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have enough information in it and the code sample is cut off after five lines. Please could you provide the XAML which contains the TextBox in question, and the code you are using to do drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one textbox then just access the textbox by name:

```
textbox1.Text
```

Or, if you need to support multiple textboxes then you can simply get the text when the drag/drop is complete.  Just handle the Drop event and check if it is a textbox that was moved:

```
private void Canvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    bool itemIsTextbox = (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TextBox)) == true);

    //get the textbox then get hte text out of it
    if (itemIsTextbox)
        string text = (TextBox)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TextBox)).Text;
}
```